# Meaning of symbol in this equality of random variables: $Z_1^2+\cdots+Z_{2m}^2\stackrel{\mathscr{L}}{=}2(E_1+\cdots+E_m)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, notation

Reading some notes on probability and statistics I found this symbol of equality between random variables (highlighted in blue). Could you explain its use better?

[image: equation_with_symbol]
Thanks in advance

Comment: My guess: It stands for equality in law (i.e. equality in distribution).

Comment: Yes, I think so, thank you very much :)